# AJAX SEO - back & forward buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, seo

I'm using Ben Almans plugin for hash change tracking:

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

Also I've modified my web configuration so that when you enter `www.mysite.com/test1`, PHP grabs string with *test1 value*, forwards it to JavaScript. JavaScript sends it through AJAX to sever side script and brings back *test1 page*.

And after all user writing `www.mysite.com/test1` in address bar gets the *test1 page*.
Everything is OK.

Now. If you enter `www.mysite.com`, you see only index page, and there is a link to *test1 page*.
If you press it, it makes address `www.mysite.com/#test1` and because of that `#` hash change plug-in can bring you back using AJAX when you press back button.

What I want is to have such hash change plug-in or method or system which will not need those `#` signs. Cause I want the user to see the same clean address like `www.mysite.com/test1`.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible. The `#` is the prefix for the hash part of the location. Hashes are usually not sent to the server, and thus, changing the hash won't cause a page request.

When you omit the sharp (that's the name of the `#` character), a page request will initiate.

If you want SEO URL's, I recommend to use this"

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var base_url = location.protocol + "//" + location.host + "/";
    $("a[href^='+base_url+']").bind("click", function(ev){
        location.hash = $(this).href.substr(base_url.length)
        ev.preventDefault();
    })
});
</script>
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/test1">Link</a>
```

This will bind an `onclick` at each `<a>` element in the document, with a `href` attribute which starts with the base url.

Comment: sorry but this method does not suits me. When user presses link I grab value of the link and pass it to php through ajax and then getting back some page draw it using jquery. I'm not going to that page phisically

Comment: My answer suits your method. You will "physically" stay at the same page, capturing all links using the `hashChange` event, while users who have disabled JS can still use the links to browse. When the hash is changed, the page does not unloads.

Comment: what about capturing back and forward pressed buttons ?

Comment: You can modify the browser history using the [`replaceState'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_replaceState%28%29.C2.A0method) method. However, when the user navigates through the history, the page will fully **reload**. When you're using hashes, the page won't fully reload.